# Initializing a Class dynamically using a string as class name

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and writing some automation framework .I want to initialize a class dynamically based on condition .

i get the name of the class as a string based on conditions .
Ex : "Vehicle_"+ typeOfvehicle => Which will on run time may be Vehicle_2Wheeler or Vehicle_3Wheeler or Vehicle_4Wheeler .

I am using if , else statement for now . But if i can initialize the class with the type of Class i want to dynamically it would be better .

I think i need to use the Reflection API but not sure how to achieve this .

Please let me know if some one has an idea of this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# Type.GetType("Truck") will return a Type that you can then instantiate

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyProject.Truck");
var instance = (Vehicle)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Though if you don't know the specific type at compile time, leave off the cast, and just use object, dynamic, or a base class.

To pass args:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type, arg1, arg2);
```